# Material UI icons are not shown in the package.json file after I attempt to download it

Tags: user-interface, material-ui

I am creating a react.js project and I've tried multiple commands, but nothing is working.

I tried
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: Did you try `npm i @material-ui/icons` command to install MUI Icon?

Comment: @SelvaS Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

up to date, audited 231 packages in 987ms

24 packages are looking for funding      
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities